# Change keys in each row of a 2d array without losing values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I have an array of rows where one (visual) column of data has two similar but different keys.  I would like to replace one of the keys so that the column has the same key in all rows.

My input array:

```
[
    ['Ttitle' => 'lilly', 'Price' => 1.75, 'Number' => 3],
    ['Title' => 'rose',   'Price' => 1.25, 'Number' => 15],
    ['Title' => 'daisy',  'Price' => 0.75, 'Number' => 25],
    ['Title' => 'nettle', 'Price' => 2.75, 'Number' => 33],
    ['Title' => 'orchid', 'Price' => 1.15, 'Number' => 7],
];
```

My desired result: (notice the key change for `lilly`)

```
[
    ['Title' => 'lilly',  'Price' => 1.75, 'Number' => 3],
    ['Title' => 'rose',   'Price' => 1.25, 'Number' => 15],
    ['Title' => 'daisy',  'Price' => 0.75, 'Number' => 25],
    ['Title' => 'nettle', 'Price' => 2.75, 'Number' => 33],
    ['Title' => 'orchid', 'Price' => 1.15, 'Number' => 7],
];
```

When I attempted to use `array_map()`, I manage to change all the keys to `Title`, but I also delete all `Title` values except for the `Ttitle` key I just changed to `Title`.

Code is as follows:

```
if (!empty($notmatchingarray))
{
    $completearray = array_merge($notmatchingarray, $datastuff2);

    $completearray = array_map(
        function($complete) {
            return array(
                'Title' => $complete['Ttitle'],
                'Price' => $complete['Price'],
                'Number' => $complete['Number'],
            );
        },
        $completearray
    );
    print_r($completearray);
}
```

Am I doing the wrong thing in using this `array_map()` function? Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better ways but I'm headed out.  With your existing code you need to set `Ttitle` or `Title` whichever is present:

```
$completearray = array_map(function($complete) {
        $title = isset($complete['Ttitle']) ? $complete['Ttitle'] : $complete['Title'];
        return array(
           'Title' => $title,
           'Price' => $complete['Price'],
           'Number' => $complete['Number'],
       );
}, $completearray);
```

[Ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary) is a shortcut for a simple `if` / `else`, so:

```
if(isset($complete['Ttitle'])) {
    $title = $complete['Ttitle']; //if Ttitle is set use it
} else {
    $title = $complete['Title'];  //if not use Title
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, works straight away. Does that $title variable basically say if the Key in $complete is Ttitle then swap $complete['Ttitle'] with $complete['Title']. And if i had all the keys with different names but similar values could i then use the same principle to change all the keys?

Comment: @Mike No, it doesn't swap the values. `?:` is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (also called the conditional operator). It's basically a compact version of an if/else statement.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using the [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function:

```
$completearray = array_map(function($complete) {
    return array(
       'Title' => (array_key_exists('Title', $complete) 
                   ? $complete['Title'] 
                   : $complete['Ttitle']),
       'Price' => $complete['Price'],
       'Number' => $complete['Number'],
   );
}, $completearray);
```

Or if you prefer:

```
$completearray = array_map(function($complete) {
    $titleKey = array_key_exists('Title', $complete) ? 'Title' : 'Ttitle';
    return array(
       'Title' => $complete[$titleKey],
       'Price' => $complete['Price'],
       'Number' => $complete['Number'],
   );
}, $completearray);
```

If the array `$complete` contains the key, `'Title'`, it will use that; otherwise it will use the key `'Ttitle'`.

Comment: @Mike What about it didn't work? Did you get an error? I had a problem in my initial answer (`in_array` instead of `array_key_exists`), but I have since corrected it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah it works now i must of jumped the gun. Great help thank you! Could i in theory expand on this to change all keys to a particular name if the multidimensional array had a lot more different keynames.?

Comment: @Mike Sure. You could tweak the second example pretty easily. You could even create an array of keys and just pick the first one that was found. whichever way you want to do it, Find the correct key and assign it to `$titleKey`. Your return statement would stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your rows of data are statically positioned, so honestly, you can just use iterated calls of `array_combine()` with your preferred keys.

If your row elements are not predictably positioned, then you can simplify/modernize the earlier posted answers with the null coalescing operator.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dPCVG))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_combine(['Title', 'Price', 'Number'], $row),
        $array
    )
);
```

Or:

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => ['Title' => $row['Ttitle'] ?? $row['Title'], 'Price' => $row['Price'], 'Number' => $row['Number']],
        $array
    )
);
```